# different way to connect with entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

It's there another way about how can I made the database connection with entity framework instead the use of connection string in the web.config. Maybe passing the parameters to the modelBuilder or to the DBContext????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that you can pass connection string in the parameter to the DataContext. What have you tried? Why do this? check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this may be useful: in the source of MyEntities:

```
public partial class MyEntities : ObjectContext
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new MyEntities object.
    /// </summary>
    public MyEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "MyEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new MyEntities object.
    /// </summary>
    public MyEntities(EntityConnection connection) : base(connection, "MyEntities")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
#endregion
....
```

**EDIT** according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042157/see-version-of-entity-framework) Q&A my EF 4 (4.1.10331.0)

and here how it look like my web.config for EF:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I hope this helps better

Comment: Hi and thanks for asking. Are you sure that the overload of the constructors are like that, it's throws me errors. It says that the overloades are this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

See the third post in this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/adodotnetdataservices/thread/2eb0e7a8-10c5-4c6c-80b8-23cb39161345

```
protected override AdventureWorksEntities CreateDataSource()
    {
        EntityConnection entityConnection = new EntityConnection();
        entityConnection.ConnectionString = "ConnectionStringConnecting to the  databaseName";
        //set other proeprties on the entityConnection
        AdventureWorksEntities dataContext = new AdventureWorksEntities(entityConnection);
        return dataContext;
     }
```